# How to Recieve Data packets from a BLE device in android application

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am an android developer and new to the `bluetooth low energy` technology here i am creating an application which is receiving some data packets from a BLE Device (it is like a embedded programmed microcontroller).I am able to connect with the device and then i have to send a command to read the data or the characteristic.I don't know ho can i proceed for the further steps to do that.I have the UUID's and those commands but not able to programme it in android.

Please help me guys.

Thanks

Best Regards

Utkarsh

Answer (score 0):

you should read out official tutorial where you can eaislly find how to get data this is link http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: can you tell me a example how to make a custom service using UUID .